# Bootstrap: how to check if an elment is checked and set it to disable if checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

This code works great but is missing something I need.
Basically if the input has a `checked="checked"` attribute, it should keep the other two elements disabled. if it is not checked the elements are enabled.

Here's my code on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gMgm7/1/

And this would be my input

```
<input class="test_priv1" type="checkbox" name="custom" id="custom" checked="checked" onclick="" />
```

I guess this would be translated to:
If my input gets a check, disable the other two elements. If my input has the checked="checked" then keep my other two elements disabled. If my input is unchecked enable the two elements.

Comment: so in your fiddle you seem to have most of that done, is the only issue that the boxes 2 and 3 get checked and they should be left unchecked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.test_priv1').is(':checked')){
         $('.test_priv2, .test_priv3').prop('disabled',true);
    }

    $('.test_priv1').change(function () {
        if(this.checked){
             $('.test_priv2, .test_priv3').prop('disabled',true);
        }else{
             $('.test_priv2, .test_priv3').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jL3e2/1/)

Comment: I dont know how else to explain it lol That code works on click. My problems is if my input was previously checked and therefore has a checked="checked" attribute those two elements should stay disabled. In this case they are not staying disabled. do you know what Im saying? :-)

Comment: Ok I updated the answer, now it checks on page load to see if the box is checked.

Comment: still not working if the item was previously checked. I'm guessing this is a bootstrap issue. so confusing

Comment: still nothing. sorry for the trouble.

Comment: sorry for all the back and forth...still need more practice w/ jquery but I got it working http://jsfiddle.net/jL3e2/1/

Answer (score 2):

@Dan had it right with checking on ready, but for some reason running `.checked` off the element does not seem to work. However, if you use `$('.test_priv1').is(':checked')` then it seems to work properly. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Prus3/1/) for an example of it working on both page load and on change.